# How to connect to mySQL Server 5.7 using Grails 3 Framework and Intellij15

Tags: java, mysql, grails, intellij-idea

I am fairly new to Grails and Intellij. Just wondering if I can get some help on connecting Grails to mySQL.  I'll provide my configuration of my Application.yml file and build.gradle file below.  Also, I'll provide you with the error message message I am receiving.

**Application.yml file**

```
            dataSource:
                pooled: true
                jmxExport: true
                driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
                username: "root"
                password: "jams"

            environments:
                development:
                    dataSource:
                        dbCreate: create-drop
                        url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DDTR?useSSL=false"
                test:
                    dataSource:
                        dbCreate: update
                        url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DDTR?useSSL=false"
                production:
                    dataSource:
                        dbCreate: update
                        url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DDTRuseSSL=false"
                        properties:
                            jmxEnabled: true
                            initialSize: 5
                            maxActive: 50
                            minIdle: 5
                            maxIdle: 25
                            maxWait: 10000
                            maxAge: 600000
                            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                            validationQuery: SELECT 1
                            validationQueryTimeout: 3
                            validationInterval: 15000
                            testOnBorrow: true
                            testWhileIdle: true
                            testOnReturn: false
                            jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                            defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

**Build.gradle file**

Basically I just added runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38" in my dependencies.

**Error Message**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -XX:CICompilerCount=3 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-async-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-bootstrap-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-compat-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-console-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-core-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-databinding-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-docs-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-encoder-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-gradle-model-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-gradle-plugin-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-gsp-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-logging-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-async-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-codecs-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-controllers-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-converters-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-databinding-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-datasource-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-domain-class-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-events-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-filters-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-gsp-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-i18n-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-interceptors-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-mimetypes-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-rest-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-services-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-testing-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-url-mappings-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-plugin-validation-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-shell-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-spring-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-taglib-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-test-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-validation-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-web-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-web-boot-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-web-common-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-web-databinding-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-web-fileupload-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-web-gsp-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-web-gsp-taglib-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-web-jsp-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-web-mvc-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-web-sitemesh-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-web-taglib-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/dist/grails-web-url-mappings-3.0.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/com.googlecode.javaewah/JavaEWAH/jars/JavaEWAH-0.7.9.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/com.jcraft/jsch/jars/jsch-0.1.50.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/jline/jline/jars/jline-2.12.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/junit/junit/jars/junit-3.8.1.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/net.sf.jopt-simple/jopt-simple/jars/jopt-simple-4.6.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.apache.ant/ant/jars/ant-1.9.4.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.apache.ant/ant-antlr/jars/ant-antlr-1.9.4.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.apache.ant/ant-junit/jars/ant-junit-1.9.4.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.apache.ant/ant-launcher/jars/ant-launcher-1.9.4.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.2.6.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/jars/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.apache.maven/maven-aether-provider/jars/maven-aether-provider-3.2.1.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.apache.maven/maven-model/jars/maven-model-3.2.1.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.apache.maven/maven-model-builder/jars/maven-model-builder-3.2.1.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.apache.maven/maven-repository-metadata/jars/maven-repository-metadata-3.2.1.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.apache.maven/maven-settings/jars/maven-settings-3.1.1.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.apache.maven/maven-settings-builder/jars/maven-settings-builder-3.1.1.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/jars/groovy-2.4.5.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-ant/jars/groovy-ant-2.4.5.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-groovydoc/jars/groovy-groovydoc-2.4.5.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-jmx/jars/groovy-jmx-2.4.5.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-json/jars/groovy-json-2.4.5.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-templates/jars/groovy-templates-2.4.5.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-xml/jars/groovy-xml-2.4.5.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-classworlds/jars/plexus-classworlds-1.2-alpha-10.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-component-annotations/jars/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-component-api/jars/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-33.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-interpolation/jars/plexus-interpolation-1.19.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-utils/jars/plexus-utils-3.0.17.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.eclipse.aether/aether-api/jars/aether-api-0.9.1.v20140329.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.eclipse.aether/aether-connector-basic/jars/aether-connector-basic-0.9.1.v20140329.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.eclipse.aether/aether-impl/jars/aether-impl-0.9.1.v20140329.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.eclipse.aether/aether-spi/jars/aether-spi-0.9.1.v20140329.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.eclipse.aether/aether-transport-file/jars/aether-transport-file-0.9.1.v20140329.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.eclipse.aether/aether-transport-http/jars/aether-transport-http-0.9.1.v20140329.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.eclipse.aether/aether-util/jars/aether-util-0.9.1.v20140329.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/jars/org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.2.201411120430-r.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/jars/jansi-1.11.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.gradle/gradle-tooling-api/jars/gradle-tooling-api-2.3.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.json/json/jars/json-20140107.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.10.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.sonatype.plexus/plexus-cipher/jars/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.sonatype.plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/jars/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.springframework/spring-core/jars/spring-core-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-cli/jars/spring-boot-cli-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependency-tools/jars/spring-boot-dependency-tools-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/jars/spring-boot-loader-tools-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/michaelrudner/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.0.12/lib/org.yaml/snakeyaml/jars/snakeyaml-1.14.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15.app/Contents/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-rt.jar" org.grails.cli.GrailsCli run-app| Running application...
            objc[96973]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
            ERROR org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
            java.net.BindException: Address already in use
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
                at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
                at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:237) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:186) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:149) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483) [spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:54) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:353) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:342) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
                at grails_help.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
            ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
            org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:237) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:186) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:149) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483) [spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:54) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:353) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:342) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
                at grails_help.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
            Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                ... 17 common frames omitted
            Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
                at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
                at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
                ... 18 common frames omitted
            ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:157) ~[spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288) ~[spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117) ~[spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689) ~[spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:54) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:353) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:342) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
                at grails_help.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:157)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:54)
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:353)
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:342)
                at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
                at grails_help.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)

            FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

            * What went wrong:
            Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
            > Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

            * Try:
            Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
            | Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Comment: The error quite clearly says that port 8080 is already in use. This has nothing to do with MySQL or frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message,

```
ERROR org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
            java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Port 8080 is already in use. You can check what is running on port 8080 and kill the process if it is not required or start your grails app in other unused ports.

It could be one of the cases where your IntelliJ or grails app failed to shutdown properly and the app kept running in background on port 8080. You can search for process and kill it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  You were correct.  I also need to get better at reading error messages :)